Address of Object within array returned by function
I am gradually porting and refactoring C code to C++.
In the original C code, I have constructs like this:
Object* obj = &objects[index];

where objects is a global Object[].
I refactored the code so the array is dynamically allocated and a different object holds the array:
struct Info {
    Object* objects;
};

Due to my gradual refactoring, I wrote the following free function:
Object* GetObjects(Info* i) {
    return i->objects;
}

Now my question is:
Does the following code behave like I would expect (getting the address of an object in the array)?:
Object* obj = &GetObjects(info)[index];

Am I getting the Address of an object in the array (what I want) here or the address of the pointer or some rvalue and invoke UB?
[] has higher precedence than & but does that also count for function calls?

If you're unsure, then always add parentheses. Or don't use pointers to begin with, use references. The less pointers you have, the less chances of pointer-related problems.

I don't think there's UB here. Also regardless of precedence I agree adding paretheses can make it clearer: Object* obj = &(GetObjects(info)[index]);

Code seems fine from a validity POV but maybe GetObjects(info) + index is a little clearer.

How about something like this? template <typename Object> struct Info { Object* objects; Object& operator[](int index) { return objects[index]; } Info(Object* objects) : objects{ objects } {} };

Oh and please don't use pointers and your own memory-handling for arrays. Use std::vector instead.

This line:
Object* obj = &GetObjects(info)[index];

Is valid, and should not cause UB by itself.
GetObjects(info) returns a Object* (not an rvalue which you were worried about), then it is accessed with operator[].
However - the code relies on the Object* array to stay alive as long as obj is used. If info is the owner of it, it will require info to stay alive as well (assuming it is responsible for its lifetime).
Notes:

Regardless of operator precedence, using paretheses will make is a bit clearer:
Object* obj = &(GetObjects(info)[index]);


Since you use C++, you can add the following method to struct info:
struct info
{
    Object * GetObjectAtIndex(int index)
    {
        // TODO: check that the index is valid and return nullptr if not
        return &(objects[index]); 
    }
};


Using references instead of pointers might help to avoid some bugs:
struct info
{
    Object & GetObjectAtIndex(int index)
    {
        // TODO: check that the index is valid, decide what to return if not
        return objects[index]; 
    }
};


It is recommended to use std::vector instead of raw C arrays. It also supports a dynamic size as you require. One caveat: std::vector might need to reallocate when enlarged, and when doing so iterators, references and pointers into it will be invalidated.


"The code relies however on the info instance, and the objects array within it to stay alive as long as obj is used."  the member is just a pointer not an array. The info instance getting destroyed has no impact on the actual array (at least not in the shown code)

I assumed  since Info is the owner of the array, and would therefore destroy it when it is destroyed. I will add a clarification.

Yes, thats my point. In the shown code Info does not own an array. Its only has a member that points to an Object

@463035818_is_not_an_ai could be. I clarrified it.

Also, regardless of whether it's a home-cooked array, a std::vector or another array implementation, most arrays will invalidate such pointers when you add items beyond their current capacity. So, be careful when you keep those pointers around, so no new items will be added during that time.

@ChristianStieber that's a valid point. I added a note about it.

@wohlstad yeah, sorry, comment removed. I first missed that you suggest to replace the array with std::vector and then the note is worth to mention
